# Using JUnit-Tools 1.1.0 to generate automatic test cases gives me "select a test-project"

Tags: java, eclipse, junit, junit-toolbox

I installed JUnit-Tools 1.1.0 in eclipse market. As per the [documentation](http://junit-tools.org/index.php/getting-started), they want the **test-projects** and the m**ock-projects** to be created manually.

My class structure is like below :
[image]

I tried creating a test package like `com.unifiedportal.core.unifiedportal.service.test` and tried generating the test classes from the JUnit-Tools..

Got an warning like below :
[image]

Let me know how i should proceed with creating the test-project for this.

Answer (score 8):

If you want to generate the tests under the same project you are in then remove `Test-project-postfix` in the junit tools preferences, otherwise let the postfix as it is and create a project (not a package) with the same name than your project plus that postfix.

Look an example of my config for generating the tests in the same project under src/test/java, because I don't want my tests to be in a separated project:

[image]

Comment: I am using eclipse mars and windos7. I didn't get any option to create a test case. I got an option as create test suit but it didn't generate test cases.

Comment: I also would like the test cases be generated inside my project. But where should I put the jar files? 
    junit-tools.jar
    jmockit.jar

Comment: @AmolPatil you have to generate it class by class(right click on the class) sadly you can't generate the test classes without a test-suite for an entire package/module

Answer (score 0):

you can add the jars as maven or gradle dependencies.Change the test-source-folder-name to src/test/java and generate the test cases using the plugin.This will generate the test cases in your test folder